# Call back URL for twitter for ios.Xamarin App

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, xamarin.ios

I have developed an application for which i need to authorise my app using google plus ,twitter and Facebook and once authorised i need to redirect to my own app.But i am unable to go back to my app for twitter and Google Plus.

```
partial  void BtnTwitter_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
      var auth1 = new OAuth1Authenticator(
         "Consumer key",
         "Consumer Secret",
         new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
         new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
         new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
         new Uri("https://twitter.com"));



        //auth1.Completed += OnAuthenticationCompleted;
        //  var ui = auth1.GetUI();

        PresentViewController(auth1.GetUI(), true, HandleAction);
        //save the account data in the authorization completed even handler
        auth1.Completed += async (s, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                loggedInAccount = eventArgs.Account;

                AccountStore.Create().Save(loggedInAccount, "Twitter");
                GetTwitterData();
                DismissViewController(true, null);

            }
        };

        var ui = auth1.GetUI();
        PresentViewController(ui, true, null);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `OAuth1` and not [`OAuth2`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/)? Also, did you already try the suggested solution mentioned on the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8564/xamarin-auth-authentication-completed-callback-not-getting-called-for-twitter-oauth-1)?

Comment: @Demitrian OAuth1 is only supported by Twitter not OAuth2.I have tried many things but got stuck in call back url.What to give in the call back url so that after login i go back to my application's screen